# case-insensitive match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have this expression: `match('(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$')`

how can I also match JPG, Jpg, jPG etc. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next RE considers names like `file.GIF` and `file.gif` as images, but not `.gif` or `file.htm`:

```
var file = "image.png";
if (/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i.test(file)) {
    alert("The file is an image")
}
```

`/.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/i` is a regular expression and `regex.test(string)` returns `true` if `string` was matched and `false` otherwise.

- `/` - begin of RE
- `.+` - matches one of more characters, e.g. `file` in `file.ext`
- `\.` - matches a literal dot
- `(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)` - matches `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png` or `gif`
- `$` marks the end of the filename
- `/` - matches the end of the RE
- `i` - **i**gnore case

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `i` flag to mark it as case-**i**nsensitive:

```
match(/.../i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [to specify `i` modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

> /i makes the regex match case insensitive.

So given any string ending with those extensions it will match regardless of the letter case.

Given the following string: ".jPg"

```
/\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i       // matches
/\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/        // doesn't match
/.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i     // doesn't match (requires filename)
```

See an [example on gskinner](http://regexr.com?2u1en)